# Positioning text and an image above a navigation bar. html/css

Tags: css, html, css-position, positioning

I am trying to create a website, where their is a logo on the left side, and text on the right (alongside the logo image) and having all that above the navigation bar, however I just cannot manage to get them into position at all!

**CSS**

```
.headerLogo{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.headerText{
    float:right;
    margin:auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="headerLogo">
<img src="Logo.gif" />
</div>

<div class="headerText">
<h1>Together, we can create change.</h1>
<p>Qui cu imperdiet temporibus, nam at autem falli, cum audire salutandi abhorreant
eu. No postea mollis lobortis pri. Natum pertinax consulatu eam an, an vix omnium
appellantur, tamquam petentium cotidieque ut pri. In sea aliquid omittantur.</p>
</div>

<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer</a></li>
        <li><a href="donate.html">Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: hello, please post what you have already done. So we can help you faster. Stackoverflow is more helpful solving specific problems rather than "do this for me"

Comment: A great starting point would be a template that looks like you want, have you tried that? Here is a site that has amazing free html 5 templates - http://html5up.net/

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused by the wording but please take a look at this solution and see if this is what you mean, otherwise I will edit the answer

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gLLa20yp/

```
img{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}

nav{

  margin-top: 5%  
}

.nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15%;
 }
```

remove the last part if you don't want a horizontal menu.

Future work: To make it look better I would suggest setting the width on the `<p>` element and giving a margin between the image and the text

Comment: afaik, images are _not_ `block` elements by default. They're inline, sometimes behaving as inline-block.

Comment: @gofrzero my bad :) thanks for the information I am editing the answer

Answer (score 0):

To set accordingly, try to give styles like below having div as position relative.

```
.headerLogo {
float:left;
margin:auto;
display:inline-block;
}   

.headerText {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 20px;
float: right;
position: relative;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to set `clearfix`, Is this the result you seek?

```css
.headerLogo{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 50%
}

.headerText{
    float:right;
    margin:auto;
    width: 50%
}

.clearFix{ clear: both};
```

```html
<div class="headerLogo">
<img src="Logo.gif" />
</div>

<div class="headerText">
<h1>Together, we can create change.</h1>
<p>Qui cu imperdiet temporibus, nam at autem falli, cum audire salutandi abhorreant
eu. No postea mollis lobortis pri. Natum pertinax consulatu eam an, an vix omnium
appellantur, tamquam petentium cotidieque ut pri. In sea aliquid omittantur.</p>
</div>

<div class="clearFix">

<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer</a></li>
        <li><a href="donate.html">Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```